# fullcalendar: total duration of all events per day in WEEK VIEW

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am having trouble understanding how to calculate the total duration of the events per day in WEEK view not month view.

So I have view of Monday through Friday and let say Monday has 3 events and each is 10 mins long. I want to calculate it to add up to 30 total and then show that 30 next to Monday in a header.

Then Friday has 2 events 20 mins each.. I need to see 40 mins next to Friday.

Currently this is what i do for EACH event:

```
  var duration = moment.duration(event.end.diff(event.start));
                var mins = duration.asMinutes();
                element.find('.fc-title').append("<span class ='timeduration'>" + " " + mins + " min." + "</span>");
```

Please help me calculate the total per each day of the week.

Comment: are you saving the event somewhere or is this supposed to be like a preview window where nothing is really saved?

Comment: I am not saving anything. The code above just shows the amount of minutes on each event based on start end date. I don't know how to implement the total per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will do:

```
var durations = [];
  
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      defaultDate: '2017-01-01',
      defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      events: [{
        title: 'event 1',
        start: '2017-01-05 11:00',
        end: '2017-01-05 13:00',
      }, {
        title: 'event 2',
        start: '2017-01-05 08:00',
        end: '2017-01-05 09:00'
      }, {
        title: 'event 3',
        start: '2017-01-06 11:00',
        end: '2017-01-06 13:00',
      }, {
        title: 'event 4',
        start: '2017-01-06 08:00',
        end: '2017-01-06 10:00'
      }],
      dayRender: function(date, cell) {
        durations[date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')] = 0;
      },
      eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
          var duration = moment.duration(event.end.diff(event.start));
          var mins = duration.asMinutes();
          var dateTotal = durations[event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')];
          durations[event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')] = dateTotal + mins;
        });

        for (var key in durations) {
          $('th.fc-day-header[data-date="' + key + '"]').append('&nbsp;<span>duration: ' + durations[key] + '</span>');
        }
      }
    });
```

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvhnjpyp/)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. THANK YOU! Dziękuję

Comment: Glad I could help! Proszę bardzo!